# how to count duplicate values if only (the same group with different values) means duplicate?

Tags: t-sql, duplicates

There is a wayplan table.
Only one route under the same principal should go and sell items to a customer.
If two route under the same principal go and sell items to the same customer, the customer is duplicated.

In first scenerio, C001 could not be said duplicate.

```
Route    Principal  Customer  Day
RO01001  RO01       C001      Day1
RO01001  RO01       C001      Day2
```

In second scenerio, C001 could be said duplicate because two routes under the same principal go and sell to the same customer.

```
Route    Principal  Customer  Day
RO01001  RO01       C001      Day1
RO01002  RO01       C001      Day2
```

Please help me in querying duplicate customers.

Comment: You could always use `SELECT Principal, Customer, Route ... GROUP BY Principal, Customer, Route HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: I can't. What you said will produce the result of first table. It is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query. You need to count distinct routes for each principal and customer.

```
SELECT Customer
FROM wayplan
GROUP BY Principal,Customer
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Route)>1
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I tried also the following code. But failed. it said distinct is not supported in windowing function. is it right?
SELECT Customer,
COUNT (DISTINCT Route) OVER(PARTITION BY Principal, Customer) As 'DuplicateCount'
FROM wayplan